# Where is docs about message.ack() and message.nack() methods?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I saw `message.nack()` somewhere, but I forgot the place.

I search them on google but got no pieces of information.

I need docs' links about `message.ack()` and `message.nack()`.

I read a book about `google pub-sub`

Here is the code:

```js
const pubsub = require('@google-cloud/pubsub')({
  projectId: 'your-project-id'
});
const topic = pubsub.topic('first-topic');
const subscription = topic.subscription('first-subscription');
subscription.pull().then((data) => {
  const message = data[0][0];
  subscription.pull().then((data) => {
    const message = data[0][0];
    console.log('Got message', message.id, 'saying', message.data);
  });
  !console.log('Got message', message.id, 'saying', message.data);
  message.ack().then(() => {
    console.log('Acknowledged message ID', message.id, 'with ackId', message.ackId);
  });
});
```

I think there are two mistakes:

1. `subscription` has no `.pull()` method
2. `message.ack()` does not return a `promise`

I test it using `"@google-cloud/pubsub": "^0.19.0",`

So I am looking for official docs about `message.ack()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[Documentation >  Node.js > Subscription](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/0.19.x/Subscription)

And the github for the Node.js library with documentation and examples [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/master/samples/subscriptions.js)

Comment: Yes. I find `message.nack()`. But the docs should be improved and explain when to use `message.nack()`.